# Why is git pushing a random file to the repos?

Tags: git

So, I'm currently in the correct folder  but when i execute 
git "push origin master", it pushes another file ?
I've tried git remote rm origin then read the origin provided by bitbucket. When i push it now both app gets pushed, both "App 1" and "App 2". App 2 is not in the same folder as my app 1, but somehow it keeps appearing. Note: App2 was an app that i've created before but has been deleted/moved.

Answer (score 0):

Git will push whatever files you have committed in the local repo, whether they are in the current directory or not.

I'd suggest doing a `git status` before the push to identify the state of all objects. Then, if there are some there you *don't* want in the remote repo, remove them from your local copy.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of presence of files of App 2 in local copy of git which you have committed  sometimes back

You can use git log command to see the history of your commits.

If it is there it will be pushed again and again,moreover if your old files are there in remote repo and you are doing git pull then those will come in local too.

Make sure it should not be there before pushing it or 
I would suggest do a fresh git init and commit the recent files.